# PHP Change Account Password Brakes at verify current password

Tags: php, sql-injection, password-hash

I am trying to make a Change You Account Password Function for my website.
The login codes are working properly, hashed passwords with bcrypt , log in verifies and confirms that the account name and password are correct with the ones that are entered.

I am trying to use the same algorithm to check the Current pass and Database pass verification ,but something seems to be missing.
I constantly get a different hash from the password that is entered and respectively wrong current password error.

Here is the exact code I use in the php file.

```
<?php
session_start();

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}

$client_new_password_err = $client_current_password_err = $client_confirm_new_password_err = $general_err = "";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT UserName FROM user_main WHERE UserName='$user_check'");
    $stmt->execute();
    foreach ($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $arr) {
        $login_session = $login_session . $arr;
    }
    if (empty($login_session)) {
        $conn = null;
        header('Location: login.php');
    }
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Email FROM user_main WHERE UserName='$user_check'");
    $stmt->execute();
    foreach ($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $arr) {
        $login_email = $login_email . $arr;
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $stmt . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (!empty($_POST["current-password"])) {
        $client_current_password = test_input($_POST['current-password']);
        $cost = [
            'cost' => 11,
        ];
        $client_current_hashed_password = password_hash($client_current_password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $cost);
    } else {
        $client_current_password_err = "No input on Current Password";
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['new-password'])) {
        $client_new_password = test_input($_POST['new-password']);
        $cost = [
            'cost' => 11,
        ];
        $client_new_hashed_password = password_hash($client_new_password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $cost);
    } else {
        $client_new_password_err = "No input on New Password";
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['confirm-new-password'])) {
        $client_confirm_new_password = test_input($POST['confirm-new-password']);
        $cost = [
            'cost' => 11,
        ];
        $client_confirm_new_hashed_password = password_hash($client_confirm_new_password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $cost);
    } else {
        $client_confirm_new_password_err = "No input on New Password";
    }
    if ($client_new_hashed_password == $client_confirm_new_hashed_password) {
      $to_change_pass = 1;  // not yet implemented
    } else {
      $to_change_pass = 0;  // not yet implemented
    }
}

if (!empty($client_current_hashed_password) && !empty($client_new_hashed_password) && !empty($client_confirm_new_hashed_password)) {
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Password FROM user_main WHERE UserName='$user_check'");
        $stmt->execute();
        foreach ($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $db_hash_pass) {
            if(password_verify($client_current_password, $db_hash_pass)) {
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE user_main SET Password = '$client_new_hashed_password' WHERE UserName = '$user_check'");
            } else {
                  $general_err = "Entered current password does not match the actual password for this account. Please try again.";
              }
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $stmt . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $conn = null;
}
?>
```

**The main question is how should I be checking if the inputted current pass matches the one on the database?** 
Should i be using the hashed version of the pass entered by the client or should i be using the plain text password?

This is the login password verify code which is 100% operational

```
if (!empty($_POST['password'])) {
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/",$_POST['password'])) {
         $usernameErr = 'Only Letters and Numbers';
    } else {
    $client_password = test_input($_POST['password']);
      if(password_verify($client_password, $hashed_password)) {
        $_SESSION['login_user'] = $client_username;
        header("location: profile.php");
```

where $hashed_password is drawn from the database column Password with username match and here it works.

As you can see I have limited passwords to letters and numbers only so -
 **Bonus question : By allowing all characters to be used in a password , does that impose any type of injection threat?**

Comment: 1. *how should I be checking if the inputted current pass matches the one on the database*: Exactly the same way you do when the user logs in. Don't hash, but verify instead. 2. no

Comment: i do that and i get a different hash everytime, and the script throws the 

    $general_err = "Entered current password does not match the actual 
    password for this account. Please try again.";

as it should of course. Thats my main problem that the script right now doesnt work, in it i have made the verify 

if(password_verify($client_current_password, $db_hash_pass))

Where client_current_password is the raw input from the user (after going thru test_input() function) and db_hash_pass is the password drawn from the DB where the username matches... that is my problem

Comment: Side note: You don't need that custom `test_input()` method and I don't know why you're using that. For your "bonus" question; don't limit passwords. One such as `123'\---<br>DELETE` is perfectly valid. Using a prepared statement, `password_hash/verify()` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Don't hash, but verify instead. – jeroen 13 mins ago

Removed hashing from the code entirely and it is ok now, it works by using password_verify($client_current_password, $db_hash_pass).

Thank you jeroen for the push u gave me to do this :D